# Align multiple backgrounds to bottom of page?

Tags: css

I'm creating a website designed by a print-designer. The background concists of two images:

one gradient that is repeteated along the y-axis and aligned with the bottom of the page
one image that is aligned with the bottom of the page and centered.(the circle)

demo:
[image]

The circle-part is pretty big and has most of the pages content on it. (~900px by ~750px).

If the page is to small I need to add scrolls. If the page is to big. I need the first image(vertical) and background-color(horizontal) to fill out the area for me. I would like to use multiple backgrounds, but the site needs IE8-support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut a 1px strip for the gradient and repeat it horizontally on the body.  Set the attachment to fixed.

Cut out the circle and place it as the background image of your content container.  This will likely be a png with transparency to allow the previous gradient to show through.

CSS

```
body {
   background: url('bg.jpg') center bottom repeat-x fixed;
}

.container {
   background: url('circle.png') no-repeat center bottom;
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-height: 750px;
   width: 900px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
    content here
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget to align it to the bottom: `background: url('bg.jpg') center bottom repeat-x fixed;`

Comment: Actually, a 1px tall/wide repeating background image causes sluggish scrolling in some browsers.  Better to go with one that's 10-20px tall/wide.

Comment: @cimmanon Never seen that before.  Can you provide a link or an article or the specific browser?

Comment: It's been a problem with Opera forever, and I'm certain seen it some older browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 to place the gradient and avoid the image altogether. Some older browsers won't support it, but it's a little more flexible than using a static gradient image.

Check out this handy generator - just select the colors and style and it will give you the code: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/